# I am facing issues with calculating the number of days between the first date of current month and Today's date using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I want to calculate the number of days between the Current date and the 1st day of the current month. If the date is the 1st of the month itself then my variable (let's call it X) should be assigned 1 else it calculates the difference.

I've tried using the `busday_count` function available in Python as shown below but it gives me the following error

```
np.busday_count((datetime.date(now.year,now.month,1)), datetime.datetime.now())
```

error

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 np.busday_count((datetime.date(now.year,now.month,1)), now)
>
> TypeError: Iterator operand 1 dtype could not be cast from
>   dtype('

Comment: How is your "now" defined?

Comment: If it is the first of the month, your code should return 0 (no date difference).

Answer (score 2):

You can go about it like this, to get number of business days since beginning of month including today:

```
np.busday_count(np.datetime64('today', 'M'), np.datetime64('today', 'D')) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[zipa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811078/zipa)'s answer will give you just the business days.

if you want all the days.

using datetime library.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
firstOfMonth = datetime(today.year, today.month, 1)
numOfDays = today - firstOfMonth
print (numOfDays.days + 1)
```

using Numpy

```
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
today = date.today()
firstOfMonth = datetime(today.year, today.month, 1)
days = np.datetime64(today) - np.datetime64(firstOfMonth) + 1
```